# Check whether an object with property value 'x' exists in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a lot of objects that I'm trying to filter out duplicates from. When an object has a property, `IMAGEURL` which is present in another object, I want to ignore this object and move on.

I'm using `nodeJS` for this so if there's a library I can use to make it easier let me know.

I've done similar implementations before with checking string values in arrays, doing something like:

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
if(arr.indexOf('foo') == -1){
   arr.push('foo')
}
```

But this won't work for objects, as best I can tell. What are my options here? To put it more simply:

```
var obj1 = {IMAGEURL: 'http://whatever.com/1'};
var obj2 = {IMAGEURL: 'http://whatever.com/2'};
var obj3 = {IMAGEURL: 'http://whatever.com/1'};

var arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var uniqueArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    // For all the iterations of 'uniqueArr', if uniqueArr[interation].IMAGEURL == arr[i].IMAGEURL, don't add arr[i] to uniqueArr
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use an inner loop (keeping track of whether we've seen the loop by using a `seen` variable -- you can actually use labels here, but I find the variable method to be easier to read):

```
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var seen = false;
    for(var j = 0; j != uniqueArr.length; ++j) {
        if(uniqueArr[j].IMAGEURL == arr[i].IMAGEURL) seen = true;
    }
    if(!seen) uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you've done `j != uniqueArr.length` and not `j < uniqueArr.length`? Don't quite see what's going on here.

Comment: @Jascination you can do `<` instead of `!=` in this case.  In this particular case, since `j` increases by `1` each step, both yield the same results.  I just use `!=` in these loops by default (opting for `<` or `>` when it is necessary)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a concise way:

```
var uniqueArr = arr.filter(function(obj){
    if(obj.IMAGEURL in this) return false;
    return this[obj.IMAGEURL] = true;
}, {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rneTR/2

#### Note: this is concise, but [orders of magnitude slower](http://jsperf.com/js-objarray-unique) than [Nirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285095/825789).

See also: http://monkeyandcrow.com/blog/why_javascripts_filter_is_slow/

Comment: You could do `uniqueArr = arr.filter(function(obj){return (uniqueArr.map(function(x){return x.IMAGEURL;}).indexOf(obj.IMAGEURL) != -1) ? false : (uniqueArr.push(obj), true);});`, but I strongly advise against it unless you know what you are doing